# how to select divs having exactly a specific text

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the example below I need `1` as the result because only one `title` has its text = `lorem ipsum`
I tried with `contains` but it counts all variations of a given criteria.

```js
var str = 'lorem ipsum';
let x = $(`.title:contains("${str}")`).length;
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum a</div>
<div class='title'>a lorem ipsum</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) on the output of your selector to restrict it to the `div` that has the exact text contents of `lorem ipsum`.

```js
var str = 'lorem ipsum';
let x = $(`.title:contains("${str}")`).filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == str;
}).length;
console.log(x);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div class='title'>lorem ipsum a</div>
<div class='title'>a lorem ipsum</div>
```

Note that since you are testing the text value twice, you could just use `$('.title')`; dependent on your HTML structure that may be faster.

Comment: maybe `$('.title').filter(function(){return $(this).text() == str;}).length;`

Comment: @qadenza absolutely you could do that. I thought if you had a lot of `title` elements it might be faster to pre-filter them.